# Are there any clustering techniques that work well on galaxy arm dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, references, unsupervised-learning

[image]

Are there any clustering techniques (k-means, GMM) that work well for this dataset?

Comment: Usually DBSCAN and variants of it work fine on such toy datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each ''arm'' should be assigned as a separate cluster both [single linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering) (hierarchical) clustering as well as [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) should work well on such an example.

Both fit the dense nature of the clusters with large sparse/empty areas separating them. Naturally the center points are problematic, but this is to be expected.